# Can we use content://contacts/people in android 2.3 API to fetch detail of contact stored in mobile

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am trying to show contact person name and his phone number using below given code using Android API 2.3

---

```
String[] ContactList= {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};  
        //Uri contact =ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;  
        Uri contact = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");  
        Cursor mycursor = this.managedQuery(contact, ContactList, null, null, null);  
        int WidgetList[] = {R.id.t1,R.id.t2,R.id.t3};  
        ListAdapter adapter = new   SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.contactview,mycursor,ContactList,WidgetList);  
        ListView lv = this.getListView();  
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

### When I tries to run this in emulator I got following errors

```
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{demo.contentprovider/demo.contentprovider.FirstActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:262)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1550)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at demo.contentprovider.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:25)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-01 16:12:03.975: E/AndroidRuntime(403):  ... 11 more
```

However if use

```
Uri contact =ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
```

Instead of

```
Uri contact = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
```

It works without any problem.
Can anyone help me why it does not work with above option.

Answer (score 0):

`Contacts.People` class has been deprecated in `level 5`. The 2.1(+) SDK's contains new contentHandler for contacts named ContactsContract, the query now moved to different, so I'm sure the URI is different too.